# ImportError: No module named main - Python

Tags: python

```
C:\Python27\radish>radish -b radish features/calculator.feature
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\radish.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named main
```

I try to run radish test. This command used to work:

```
radish -b radish features/calculator.feature
```

but right now I have no idea why it doesn't work anymore... Any idea?

Comment: from radish import given, when, then... when I mouse hover at imports 'from ' is underlined and there's written [pylint] E0611: No name 'given' in module 'radish'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*__init__.py* from one of my directories caused a problem. I had to delete it.